# Side Navigatiob Bar in Cypress

Tags: angular, cypress

I am working with side nav bar testing here icons are placed instead of text, i want to know how to click the side nav bar with icons in cypress?

Comment: Aashifa: Your question seems to be broad; request you to add more information so that we can help you. Also, please go through this document - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you can expose part of the html source of the side nav bar we can probably help you.

Comment: i don't know how to write code for side nav bar with icon click

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't provide any extra information, just a wild guess with something with an icon, inside a side nav bar and a click:

```js
cy.get('#side-nav-bar')
  .find('#icon_name')
  .click()
```

If you want more detailed information how to click an icon in a side nav bar we need the following information:
1. A unique identifier of the side-nav-bar
2. A unique identifier of the icon